# auto incrementar con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un sistema de votación que debería autoincrementarse al presionar sobre unos link, básicamente la estructura es la siguiente:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Uno <a href="#">0</a></li>
  <li>Dos <a href="#">0</a></li>
  <li>Tres <a href="#">0</a></li>
</ul>
```

Al presionar los enlaces con ceros, estos tienen que incrementar de uno en uno, actualizarse y guardarse en la base de datos, esto último lo hago mediante AJAX.

Tanto los nombres como los enlaces los cargo desde la base de datos. Lo ideal seria que si presionase el enlace 'Dos' se mostrara lo siguiente:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Uno <a href="#">0</a></li>
  <li>Dos <a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li>Tres <a href="#">0</a></li>
</ul>
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo autoincrementar los valores? Gracias

Comment: Buenas Johan, echale un vistazo mejor al problema, es un problema sencillo de javascript, te recomiendo que crees variables globales, que las inicialices y las incrementes cuando el ajax pase por la función sucess. O que modifiques el PHP y retornes como respuesta el numero total de votos. Saludos!

Comment: hola Johan. Preguntas por sugerencias y eso seria basado en opiniones, un motivo de cierre de preguntas. Has de determinar tú la manera e intentar desarrollarla. Si en el proceso tienes dudas concretas y especificas, preguntalas pulsando en [edit] y siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. un saludo

Comment: Creo que la etiqueta AJAX sobra

Comment: Esto pasa probablemente porque `0` es `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como realizarlo con jQuery muy simple.

Si tienes alguna duda me dices.

```js
$('li').on('click',function(){
    var actual = $(this).find('a').text();
    var now = parseInt(actual) + 1;
    $(this).find('a').text(now);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Uno <a href="#">0</a></li>
  <li>Dos <a href="#">0</a></li>
  <li>Tres <a href="#">0</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hola ntzz, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Muchas gracias por responder pero esta pregunta es muy amplia ya que pide sugerencias. Es mejor esperar a que el autor explique su problema concreto tras haberlo intentado ya que aqui se ayuda a resolver errores, no tareas. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo !

Comment: @lois6b ya se como funciona SO gracias, si la persona pregunta sugerencias para como incrementar los valores, la pregunta está correctamente formulada y mi respuesta fundamentada en su pregunta, si no es lo que busca o no le vale, expondrá de forma mas detallada su explicación y por lo tanto una mejor respuesta.

Comment: hola ntzz. Esto no es SO, es SOes. Donde el idioma no es lo unico que cambia. Preguntas que son validas en SO pueden no serlo aqui porque intentamos que el usuario que pregunta haya trabajado más las cosas antes de preguntar. Mira mi comentario en la pregunta para ver a qué me refiero.  Las sugerencias son motivos de cierre actualmente. Revisa [meta] para más info. Un saludo